# Implementing Dynamic time warping for image matching

Tags: c++, image-processing, pattern-matching, dynamic-programming

Let's say I have 2 images containing the Word "CAT" but with different sizes and i want to apply DTW to check that both images have the same words.

i used the code implemented here 
http://bytefish.de/blog/dynamic_time_warping/

but the problem is that i only have 2 vectors and when these vectors have elements more than 800 the program crashes

so my question is:
Is it efficient to take the whole picture and put it into a vector and apply DTW for these 2 vectors ?
or shall I divide the pictures into slices(windows) and compare these slices with each others ? and in this case what if an image has 15 slice and the other has only 10 slices , how can i compare between them ?

finally if there's any source that explain implementing DTW for image matching please pass it to me.

Comment: What platform are you implementing this on? Vectors of size 800 should not be an issue on any average modern computing platform. I have a feeling the problem lies elsewhere. Also, how are you using code for 1D DTW for matching 2D images?

Comment: I am using Opencv C++ with codeblocks , you can try the code and tell me .
btw I transform the 2D images into 1-D vector and then pass it to the DTW

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I don't think you can simply do the transformation 2D to 1D and apply DTW. This is not a Neural Network. Can you explain whether you think this is applicable? Or did you maybe manage to do this? If so, how?